# asprotect ske unable to get hardware id

Tags: c++, c, encryption, packer

I'm using asprotect ske . everything is OK...
Everything is ok..but one of problem is
To get user hardware id ,I send `test.exe` software which compiled from /Reg Trial/Delphi 
folder offered by asprotect sample folder.
But one of problem is when execute `test.exe` application 
it show debug log and also other kind of information about asprotect.
What is easiest method to get user’s hardware id and securely?
I don’t want to show user see asprotect popup or info.
anyone guide me much appreciate

Comment: http://www.aspack.com/contact.html ?

Comment: they don't reply...their support is not good.